# Drawing on top of fullscreen applications in Java

Tags: java, graphics, fullscreen

I'm working on a project in java where I need to draw something to the screen (more specifically a crosshair), and make it stay on top of any other application at all time, including fullscreen applications such as games. So far I've tried creating a transparent window and calling setAllwaysOnTop(true), and then drawing onto it. But this doesn't work over fullscreen applications.

What I need is basically something similar to [this](http://directdrawoverlaylib.codeplex.com/). Is it possible in Java? Or am I better of switching to maybe c++?

Comment: Full Screen Exclusive mode, in which mode a lot of games will run, is just, exclusive, meaning that no other Window can draw or update the screen, this allows the application in question to gain greater performance enchantments as it doesn't need to compete with other processes which might want to update the screen independently of them.  I don't know it's possible or not, but I would say it would very, very difficult

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible with java.

> Some platforms may not support always-on-top windows, some may support only some kinds of top-level windows; for example, a platform may not support always-on-top modal dialogs.

Java can not guarantee even trivial "always-on-top" support for different platforms. So you need to discover exactly platform you want, maybe you will need even your own drivers or some modification of them.